# Gold nugget storage

Tags: code-golf

Given a positive integer, write it as the sum of numbers, where each of them is in \$\{kt|k\in{1,9,81},t\in{1,2,3,...,64}\}\$. How many numbers at least are used? Shortest code win.

Samples:

```
Input  Output Method
1      1      1
2      1      2
64     1      64
65     2      64+1
72     1      72
343    2      342+1
576    1      576
577    2      576+1
5184   1      5184
46656  9      5184+5184+5184+5184+5184+5184+5184+5184+5184
5274   2      5184+90
```

[image]

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16547/)

Comment: Could you give slightly more detail/put into words how the input results in the output?

Comment: @Quintec All numbers in column `Method` are in the given set, and there's no way to make fewer ones that sum to the input

Comment: If something requires clarification in the comments, it would be useful to edit the challenge to include that clarification

Comment: @trichoplax I don't know where to insert it

Comment: Is it basically a sort of [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) ? With the coins denominations being in the set `{1,9,81} × {1...64}` ?

Comment: Change making problem for minecraft gold nuggets apparently

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the number of items or number of stacks?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk number of stacks for minecraft picture, item(numbers to be added) for the problem

Comment: I suggest adding `5274 = 64*81 + 10*9` as a test case, this checks if answers take as many blocks as possible if there are more than 576 nuggets and get  `64*81 + 1*81 + 9*1` (as mine did)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
64R×9;Ɗ⁺ff€¥@ŒṗẈṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//NjRSw5c5O8aK4oG6ZmbigqzCpUDFkuG5l@G6iOG5gv///zU4)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Explanation (you can't test for inputs larger than `58` over TIO):

```
64R×9;Ɗ⁺ff€¥@ŒṗẈṂ Arguments: x
64R               [1..64]
   ×9;Ɗ           Multiply by 9, prepend to original list
       ⁺          Do the above once more
             Œṗ   Positive integer partitions of x
           ¥@     Call with reversed arguments (x = partitions, y = flattened outer product)
         f€         For each partition in x, keep the elements that are in y
        f           Keep the elements of x that have remained intact after the above
               Ẉ  Lengths of the remaining partitions
                Ṃ Minimum
```

Comment: Since the output in testable area is trivial, can't quite check?

Comment: @l4m2 You can't do so over TIO, but you *might* be able to do so if you install Jelly locally. That's why I've added the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> <s>66</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @nwellnhof*

```javascript
f=n=>n&&1+f(n<5184?n>64&&n%(n<576?9:n>719?81:72):n-5184)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDRCoMgFEDf9xW@TJRood20YtW3RKuxEdexxn7fKcGw3MN8EOQczsV779/9Mjxvj1eK5jJaOzXYtEipSCaG50KU0GGrgFI8@rdWXVVjq0XVlaLWkteYeonbweBi5vE0myubmCDucE6yjAjCBD9ssdxguccKQqwg4sWXS8@TaICWYUFHE3LIg0IOMk64vwYJ94oFHTSc8KPhVhM0/KJ2BihVqNWoViP58@L2Aw)

Comment: @nwellnhof This would fail for several values (576, 632, 633, ...)

Comment: I see. But `f=n=>n&&1+f(n<5184?n>64&&n%(n<576?9:n<648?72:81):n-5184)` (56 bytes) should work, right?

Comment: @nwellnhof Yes, it does. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
ŽK≠‰`91vDy64*›i1sy9*%]64/îO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9vc2FiaWX//8W9S@KJoOKAsGA5MXZEeTY0KuKAumkxc3k5KiVdNjQvw65P/8Ov/zQ2NjU2) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a9cVvn/6F7vR50LHjVsSLA0LHOpNDPRetSwK9OwuNJSS7W21sxE//A6//@H1@v8N1AwVDBSMDNRMDNVMDdSMDYxVjA1NwNicwVTQwsTEGGqYGpkbqJgYmZmagYA)

*-3 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

This is my first 05AB1E submission, so I am sure that this can be optimized.

Comment: Not sure why you opted to choose the legacy version, since your answer also works in the new Elixir rewrite, but in the new version `5184` can be `ŽK≠`. In addition, the `S` after `91` can be removed since it's done implicitly; and `}}` can be `]` (although you'd still need `}}` in your test suite on TIO). [Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9vc2FiaWX//8W9S@KJoOKAsGA5MXZEeTY0KuKAumkxc3k5KiVdNjQvw65P/8Ov/zQ2NjU2) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a9cVvn/6F7vR50LHjVsSLA0LHOpNDPRetSwK9OwuNJSS7W21sxE//A6//@H1@v8N1AwVDBSMDNRMDNVMDdSMDYxVjA1NwNicwVTQwsTEGGqYGpkbqJgYmZmagYA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I used the legacy version because tio.run/#05ab1e redirects there and because I didn't know about multiple versions.Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Ah, I see. The legacy version is written in Python, and was used for the past few years. A few months back the Elixir rewrite was released as new version, with loads of new features. Some builtins have changed slightly, so I do still use the legacy version sometimes, but I mostly use the new version now. :) PS: If you haven't seen it yet: [Tips for golfing in 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96361/52210) might be interesting to read through. And feel free to ask anything in the [05AB1E chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33375/05ab1e-oasis) if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 47 bytes

```perl6
{+($_,(*X-(1,9,81 X*^65)).grep(*>=0).min...^0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtNCsIwEIX3nmIWIpk4hsYkkxSp5@iq4qIRwdqSrop49pi4eB@P97OM6cV52uAQocufo9jfSMj@JDS1FDT0cmCHqB5pXIS8dg2q6flWSg0NfvNlt943iOWEEOcEmuBMwLbIEfjijTUEznOFL9ChlJbZcd2FivYfm/wD)

A greedy algorithm seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 66 bytes

```
Min[Length/@IntegerPartitions[#,All,Union[#,9#,81#]&@Range@64,#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYrLCsIwEEV/ZSDQ1Uhpm0ddKHEpKBTBVegiSNoG2hHq7MRvj7M795y7RV7SFjm/YpngVO6Zwi3RzEvtr8RpTvsQd86c3/QJCi/rik@SIXxU2DdqrPwj0py81ajGsSrDnomDgsMZpiAGKqg9fBuEFkFOYA2CE@50h2CcFeOcUNNL1NYaMaZ1@lf@)